# Change console output language

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

I have set my locale to English in the TFS 2017 web interface and all the texts now appear in English. However, the language used in the console output window (where the steps being executed are shown while the build runs) remains unchanged. What do I have to do to change it as well?

Both here:

[image: Console]

here:

[image: Logs]

and here:

[image]

Comment: Did you mean the build log language or just the language in console interface.  Suggest you to add  a screen shot to make this more clear.

Comment: Please reword your answer to directly answer my question (instead of a comment) and I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the **system language** of your Build server and TFS server.

If it's not English, change it and queue the build again.

Comment: I succeeded in changing the web portal language the way you described already before.

Comment: @David Could you add a screenshot to show which part is still no English?

Comment: @David According to your screenshot, this may due to build server language. Double check the **system language** of your build server and TFS server. If it's not English, change it and queue the build again.